# Passing multiple values to a function in Pandas to choose a value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get to grips with Pandas and I know that iterating over rows in pandas is something you should only do if you really have no other option (I think so anyways?)

My scenario is:

I have a list of data with 3 columns.

Each column has a different entry for example:

| Color 1 | Color 2 | Color 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blue | Red | Green |
| Green | Purple | Black |

I want to go over every row and call a function like

```py
def choose_color(list_of_colors_in_row):
   if "Blue" in list_of_colors_in_row:
      return "Blue"
   else:
     return list_of_colors_in_row[0]
```

And add this to a new column in the dataframe.

So in the example table, it would add a new column with Blue, Green (The function is just an example)

I know I could do this by iterating over the rows, but I was wondering if there is a better way? I think you aren't supposed to edit a dataframe when you are iterating over it right?

I've looked up the apply function and thought that might do it - but I can't seem to figure out how to pass all 3 of the values in the arguments.

Apologies if this is a silly question - I really appreciate any help from anyone. Thank you!

Comment: Using `.apply` is correct. But use `axis='columns'` as argument to apply as well. It will then call the function with each row as input. Which is pretty much what you already have. `df['new_column'] = df.apply(choose_color, axis='columns')` may already do it for you. The size of row doesn't matter: your "list_of_colors_in_row" is simply a single row of the dataframe, which contains exactly that (unless you have different columns that you don't show in the question; but that's easily bypassed).

Comment: Don't bother too much with fixing the table. Instead, provide actual code that creates the example dataframe, for copy-pasting (e.g., into an answer). It's hard(er) to copy-paste a fancy looking table into example-answer code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) Am I wrong in thinking that it would pass the value of the 1 column only, not all 3 in the row? That seems to be my problem, I need to pass a list of all 3 colors in 1 row to pick one, but I think apply would send each color individually - or am I not right there?

Comment: And of course, thank you for the advice. Let me write up some example code that runs :)

Comment: "Am I wrong in thinking that it would pass the value of the 1 column only, not all 3 in the row?" - yes (you are wrong in thinking that): it passes the *complete row* as a single argument. That's why there is an `axis` parameter: you can either pass complete rows, or complete columns, depending on the use case.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense haha! It worked! Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to 9769953 for the help

This is the working code I got:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'color_1': ['Blue', 'Green'],
        'color_2': ['Red', 'Purple'],
        'color_3': ['Green', 'Black'],
        }
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def choose_color(row):
    list_of_colors_in_row = [row["color_1"], row["color_2"], row["color_3"]]
    if "Blue" in list_of_colors_in_row:
        return "Blue"
    else:
        return list_of_colors_in_row[0]

df["New Column"] = df.apply(choose_color, axis=1)


print(df.head())
```

Comment: The conversion from the row to a list is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try either one of these;
Apply Lambda passes row in a loop...

```
def choose_color(list_of_colors_in_row):
   if "Blue" in list_of_colors_in_row:
      return "Blue"
   else:
     return list_of_colors_in_row[0]
 
df["New_Column"] = df.apply(lambda x: choose_color(x), axis=1)
```

Or;

```
df["New_Column1"] = df.apply(lambda x: "Blue" if "Blue" in x else x[0], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Sachin - I got the answer from 9769953 but thank you for contributing regardless :) <3

Comment: @JeffreyWinger It is appreciated if you mark an answer as accepted, to show that your problem has been resolved. That may be your own answer, but as per my comment there, that is unnecessary convoluted. In fact, I had accidentally written the exact same answer as this one (now deleted), including the variant with the lambda function, so you may want to accept this one instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where`:

```
df['new_column'] = np.where((df == 'Blue').any(axis=1), 'Blue', df['Color 1'])
```

where `np.where` is basically an if-else, statement. If any of the columns contain Blue, it will return Blue, otherwise it will return `df['Color 1']`